# Camera and Gallery doesnt open on some phone models for Android app

Tags: java, android, camera, gallery

Ok we use some code to open gallery and camera on android devices,  users select a photo and it loads it in as normal.

But on some phones it doesnt work, like on Nokia 2.2 phone.

```
private void takeCameraImage() {
        Dexter.withActivity(getActivity())
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            File file;
                            try {
                                file = getImageFile(); // 1
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("exception","=="+e.getMessage()+" "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                return;
                            }
                            Uri uri;
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) // 2
                                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.concat(".provider"), file);
                            else
                                uri = Uri.fromFile(file); // 3
                            pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri); // 4
                            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
```

This is the code the dev says he users in java.  Can anyone understand why it works on some phones and not others?

Comment: `file = getImageFile();` ? No code posted.

Comment: It will depend on the Android version of the phone.

Comment: But on some phones it "doesnt" work, like on Nokia 2.2 phone.